# UIKit Swift 5: How to update UI every new minute

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to update a countdown timer on my UI that counts down in minutes, so I need to update it *every start of a new minute*, which is not the same as updating every minute. My current solution is initializing a timer that calls the `updateUI()` function every tenth of a second, which is far from ideal:

`timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector:#selector(TimesViewController.updateUI), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`

Is there a way to call that function every start of a new minute?

Comment: What do you mean with `start of a new minute` ?

Comment: @omerfarukozturk I mean at the beginning of the first minute of the day, the the second minute of the day, and so on. Explained another way, every time the second arrow on an analog clock hits 12.

Comment: I added an answer related to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create timer that checks system date in each second. For example;

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { (_) in
    let second = Calendar.current.component(.second, from: Date())
    if second == 0 {
        // new minute
        updateUI()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to do it without using a timer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be precise and only fire the timer exactly once per minute...

Add this extension to `Calendar` to calculate the start of the next minute:

```
extension Calendar {
    
    func startOfNextMinute(after startDate: Date = Date()) -> Date {
        let components = dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: startDate)
        guard let startOfCurrentMinute = Calendar.current.date(from: components) else { fatalError("\(#function) Unable to create valid Date") }
        guard let startOfNextMinute = date(byAdding: .minute, value: 1, to: startOfCurrentMinute) else { fatalError("\(#function) Unable to create valid Date") }
        return startOfNextMinute
    }
}
```

Then setup a `Timer` like this:

```
private var timer: Timer?

func setNextUpdateTimer() {
    timer?.invalidate()
    let startOfNextMinute = Calendar.current.startOfNextMinute()
    
    timer = Timer(fire: startOfNextMinute, interval: 0, repeats: false, block: { _ in
        // call your update action here
        self.setNextUpdateTimer()
    })
    
    if let configuredTimer = timer {
        configuredTimer.tolerance = 0.2
        RunLoop.main.add(configuredTimer, forMode: .common)
    }
}
```

Note: When the `Timer` is no longer needed be sure to call `timer?.invalidate()` to prevent the timer from firing again and to remove it from the `RunLoop`. A good place to do this is in the `deint` of the class it belongs to:

```
deinit {
    timer?.invalidate()
}
```